# Fast reports missing on tool palette

Tags: components, delphi-xe8, fastreport

Im using delphi XE8 on a project that requires a form to be created from DB data.
My team was formerly using Rave Reports on XE4 version to do this but we decided to upgrade and use Fast reports 5.0.

The problem is: When I create a new Unit, all Fast Reports tools doesn't appear on the tool palette, I checked and all packages are installed (via Project > Options > Packages).

[image: Components]

[image]

The weird thing is that when I create a new project, and a new Unit, all Fast Reports tools appear.

Can someone help me?

Comment: the down-voter can please explain why the -1??

Comment: The Tool Palette is context sensitive.  It doesn't display things that are not relevant to the current state of the IDE.  Design-time components are not relevant to **Units**, only to the **Form Designer**.  The Form Designer must be active and focused in order to see components in the Tool Palette. Is that the case in your situation?

Comment: @RemyLebeau unfortunately no, I used the same process when creating the new Unit in the other project, and its active

Comment: A **Unit** is just a source file. Does it have an associated DFM? Is that DFM active in the Form Designer when the Tool Palette is visible? You keep saying "new Unit" when you should be saying "new Form" or "new DataModule" or "new Frame", things that actually use components.

Comment: Do you use XE8 with all updates? It may be an IDE bug which fixed in the updates

Comment: @RemyLebeau its a bad habit, its a new form

Comment: @gpi im using XE8 with no updates and fast reports fxm2

Comment: FR 5 VCL will not available in the FMX application. Use FR FMX 2.5.9 for FMX (Windows and OSX) applications only

Comment: @gpi k, I'll try it, ty very much

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for the wrong term. FastReport components starts by **frx** prefix:

[image]

Comment: that's true, I'll edit the question with a propper screen shot of the search, but if I search for the prefix "Trx" nothing comes up.